# Stuck on LearnStreet Lesson 6.9

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to Ruby and have been using LearnStreet to get started, and now I'm stuck.

**The Question:**

Now, combining string interpolation with method calls, can you complete the method name_length to return the string, "Jack's first name has x letters and last name has y letters".

**The Hint:**

Hint 1
Type the code "#{first_name}'s first name has #{first_name.length} letters and

**My Answer:**

```
def name_length(first_name, last_name)
    "#{first_name}'s first name has #.{first_name.length} letters and #{last_name} has #{last_name.length} letters"
end
```

**What Happens When I Run It:**

"Are you returning the correct value? Have you used string interpolation and called length method on first_name and last_name?"

**Something interesting:**

If I write puts before my answer I get this:

Jill's first name has 4 letters and Anderson has 8 letters
"Your method does not return a value"

but the question is looking for Jack...so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"#{first_name}'s first name has #{first_name.length} letters and #{last_name} has #{last_name.length} letters"`. You do not need to interpolate last name, it is to be `and last name has`

Comment: To expand a little bit on what BroiSatse said, the problem isn't that it's Jill instead of Jack.  That's just a matter of what args get passed.  The problem is that you interpolated last_name, when you should have entered it literally (not in #{})

Answer (score 0):

1. your method should not use `puts` - it sounds like the code is expecting it to just return the value of the string that you generate - so just remove the `puts`
2. as @BroiSatse says - you don't need to use `#{last_name}` - the answer calls for the words "last name" so replace that in your string
3. you have a `.` between the `#` and `{` in your code example... that is probably a typo, but if you have it in your real code it break things.